# to project a 2D text onto 3D curved surface in Blender

Tags: blender

Although I searched in a lot of website, unfortunately, I could not find a sample or tutorial about how a 2D text is projected onto 3D curved surface in Blender. Up to now, I could not receive any answer  from the StackOverFlow site also.

I know that this similar question is repeated by me. Sorry for this.

Regards

Comment: What does Blender have to do with this? I don't think you can script it using C# (It uses Python for scripting as far as I know)

Comment: I have a 3D object and want to reflect the number onto it. And then I'll export this in XAML format into C# project.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in C#? Doing it in Blender is probably lots easier, but I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by wanting to 'reflect' a number onto the surface - do you want to texture it with an image containing a number or do you want to project the number onto the object? Do you want to do this in c# to be able to generate lots of different images?

Comment: I am searching a code snippet for this purpose. If not possible, I want to learn how to do the projecting process in Blender, AC3D. Thanks.

Comment: Blender and AC3D are not programming languages, are they?

Comment: @Longman: You don't happen to be related to Richman25? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995694/3d-object-in-blender

Comment: You might want to stop posting the same thing over and over again, each time with a new user name (http://stackoverflow.com/users/243704/longman http://stackoverflow.com/users/242767/richman25 ) and start 1. thinking about whether this is actually a *programming* question, which is what StackOverflow is for, and 2. if so, how to ask it in a way such that people can actually help you.

Comment: Here, a sample code or tutorial means explanation about the subject. That is, one that is familiar with the subject can guide the owner of a question. Everyday, a lot of new user come into StackOverFlow. Maybe, one of them can answer the question.

Comment: @balpha is 100% correct. Don't keep spamming with this same question, and this isn't *really* programming related.

Comment: In Addition to the above, I'll trust the power of the StackOverFlow site. Isn't this a pride for your site ? I'm glad of StackOverFlow. 
A lot thanks to their founders.

Comment: Sirs, my goal is not to make spamming. Please be sure of this. There are many unanswered questions in this site. If a question is not new, unfortunately, nearly nobody becomes awear of the question. Sorry for the repeated questions. If you say me "Please don't enter this site from now on, I can never enter. Regards

Comment: Some tutorial [here](http://www.geeks3d.com/20090925/tutorial-discovering-blender-part-3-applying-uv-mapping/). I know this is possible -- wait a second -- it was something like this: select a side in edit mode and unwrap, then there was some option to draw things to black background without textures or images, researching...

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

The idea is to generate UV map from 3D model and assign a texture to it.

1. Select your model and switch to editmode (If you are in object mode, you need to press "tab")
2. Unwrap 3D model to get UV map by pressing: U -> Unwrap
3. Open the UV/Image editor
4. Open image: containing the text by clicking: Image -> Open Image
5. Make adjustments to correctly map the image
6. Switch to object mode in 3D view
7. View the model in textured mode, the image should be now mapped to the 3D model

Play around with Mapping section of Texture tab in Properties section to change the projection.

Detailed tutorial [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D%3a_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics)